# ServiceStack: Is it expected to create a new class for each return type we expect?

Tags: servicestack

I have a repository class called FooRepository which has the ability to get various objects from a database.

I currently have one business object class called FooObject, which contains all the properties that I care about (Id, Name, CreatedDate, etc)... but my problem is that since ServiceStack only allows one DTO per route, I find myself unable to create more than one API method on my service to get back different types of data from my repository.

So, is it normal in ServiceStack to create a bunch of DTOs that simply return different types of data from the same repository? In ASP/MVC, this is rather easy because there's no route mapping clash going on, and I can simply create 'X' number of methods without the need to tie them to a specific DTO.

Thanks,
-Mario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each operation should have its own DTO. Keep in mind that the same DTO can be used for different HTTP methods(GET, PUT, POST, DELETE)

Comment: Just to confirm, it's normal to have a bunch of empty DTO classes with literally no code in them, simply for the purpose of mapping a route to a new method?

Comment: Yep, exactly. The DTOs are just full of properties that represent the data for requests and responses. They DTOs can also contain validation logic